# EWS - determine if an attendee is a room or resource instead of a person

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Given an `Attendee` in EWS, how can I determine if that attendee is a room or a resource, instead of a person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing would be just check if the Attendee is in the Resources Strongly typed property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.calendaritemtype.resources(v=exchg.80).aspx if your getting a Calendar Item using EWS this is where Rooms and Resources will be returned vs Required and optional attendees.

If the Attendee is in the Global Address list and you have 2013 or greater then you can also use FindPeople and check the PersonaType returned eg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body >
    <m:FindPeople>
      <m:PersonaShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
      </m:PersonaShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView BasePoint="Beginning" MaxEntriesReturned="100" Offset="0"/>
      <m:ParentFolderId>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="directory"/>
      </m:ParentFolderId>
      <m:QueryString>Adams@ddddd.onmicrosoft.com</m:QueryString>
    </m:FindPeople>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

should return something like the following for a room

```html
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="629" MinorBuildNumber="8" Version="V2016_07_13" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <FindPeopleResponse ResponseClass="Success" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ResponseCode>NoError</ResponseCode>
            <People>
                <Persona xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                    <PersonaId Id="AAUQAGDlxBsmUDpClBbAI1WX04o=" />
                    <PersonaType>Room</PersonaType>
                    <CreationTime>0001-01-02T00:00:00Z</CreationTime>
                    <DisplayName>Conf Room Adams</DisplayName>
                    <DisplayNameFirstLast>Conf Room Adams</DisplayNameFirstLast>
                    <DisplayNameLastFirst>Conf Room Adams</DisplayNameLastFirst>
                    <FileAs />
                    <EmailAddress>
                        <Name>Conf Room Adams</Name>
                        <EmailAddress>Adams@dddddd.onmicrosoft.com</EmailAddress>
                        <RoutingType>SMTP</RoutingType>
                        <MailboxType>Mailbox</MailboxType>
                    </EmailAddress>
                    <EmailAddresses>
                        <Address>
                            <Name>Conf Room Adams</Name>
                            <EmailAddress>Adams@dddddd.onmicrosoft.com</EmailAddress>
                            <RoutingType>SMTP</RoutingType>
                            <MailboxType>Mailbox</MailboxType>
                        </Address>
                    </EmailAddresses>
                    <RelevanceScore>2147483647</RelevanceScore>
                </Persona>
            </People>
            <TotalNumberOfPeopleInView>0</TotalNumberOfPeopleInView>
            <FirstMatchingRowIndex>0</FirstMatchingRowIndex>
            <FirstLoadedRowIndex>0</FirstLoadedRowIndex>
        </FindPeopleResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```